# Attempt to solve the nonlinear pendulum 2nd order differential equation using 4th order Runge-Kutta method, not getting expected result

Tags: python, matplotlib, numerical-methods, runge-kutta

I am new to Python, so I have restricted the process to matplotlib only, not going into NumPy.

I followed the book "Scientific Computing in Python" by Abhijit Kar Gupta, to write the Python script to solve a 2nd-order differential equation using the 4th order Runge-Kutta method.

In the book, the example the author gave was a simple one. But for my problem, the **nonlinear pendulum** (where small angle approximation sin(x)~x is inaccurate), I tried to modify the functions as I expected would be necessary.

I am trying to plot the variation of the angle (x) vs. time (t). But I don't think I am getting the correct output. The nature of a pendulum released at an angle of x = 170° is given here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pendulum_(mechanics)#/media/File:Pendulum_170deg.gif.

Though I'm finding it for x = 160° = 8.0*pi/9.0 radians, still the plot should look somewhat like a sinusoidal oscillation, with a non-uniform period. But all I'm getting is something like a suddenly stopped pendulum.

Please tell me where I am doing it wrong. Also, what should I do if, rather than looking at the plot, I want to get a list-like output, like a table with two columns for time and angle? Also also, what should be done so that we shall get the angle for a particular time (that is, for any external input)?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
Python 3.12.0 (tags/v3.12.0:0fb18b0, Oct  2 2023, 13:03:39) [MSC v.1935 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.

# Solving a non-linear pendulum equation of motion using RK4 method:
# Equation of Motion: d^x/dt^2 + k.sin(x)=0, where 'x' is angle, k=g/l. We take g=10m/s^2, l=10m, so k=1(s^{-2}).
# We modify the single 2nd order differential equation as a system of linear equations, consisting of two 1st order differential equation: (1) dx/dt=y=f1(x,y,t), (2) dy/dt=-k.sin(x)=f2(x,y,t).

from math import sin, pi

# Defining two functions-
def f1(t,x,y): return y

def f2(t,x,y): return -k*sin(x)

k=1.0                      #parameter
t,x,y=0,8.0*pi/9.0,0             #initial values (t: second, x: radian, y: (initial angular velocity) radian/second)
h=0.01                   #increment in t
T,X,Y=[t],[x],[y]          #lists to store data

# Loop starts with RK4 steps:
for i in range(200):
    a1=h*f1(t,x,y)                      
    b1=h*f2(t,x,y)                      
    a2=h*f1(t+0.5*h,x+0.5*a1,y+0.5*b1)  
    b2=h*f2(t+0.5*h,x+0.5*a1,y+0.5*b1)  
    a3=h*f1(t+0.5*h,x+0.5*a2,y+0.5*b2)  
    b3=h*f2(t+0.5*h,x+0.5*a2,y+0.5*b2)  
    a4=h*f1(t+h,x+a3,y+b3)              
    b4=h*f2(t+h,x+a3,y+b3)              
    x=x+(1/6)*(a1+2*a2+2*a3+a4)         # apprx. value of x1 for t+h
    y=y+(1/6)*(b1+2*b2+2*b3+b4)         # apprx. value of y1 for t+h
    t=t+h                               # current value of independent variable t
    T.append(t)
    X.append(x)
    Y.append(y)

    
# for plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(T,X,lw=3)
[<matplotlib.lines.Line2D object at 0x00000190D0CD5910>]
plt.xlim(0,50)    # xlim is just time range
(0.0, 50.0)
plt.ylim(-pi,pi)  # ylim is the range of angle (in radians)
(-3.141592653589793, 3.141592653589793)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

And the plot I got:

[image]

If I zoom the blue line:

[image]

This is in no way close to a general pendulum. Why is the solution stopping abruptly?

Comment: Dunno what's happening in this particular, but anyway, some general advice. Try a range of initial conditions. For small amplitude, the solution should be very close to exactly sinusoidal, and should get more non-sinusoidal as amplitude increases. You can verify whether that's what you see. Also, look at the direction field (i.e. plot vectors (dx/dt, dy/dt) over x, y as arrows). You should find that solutions, whatever the initial conditions, are following the arrows.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Why do you say the solution is wrong? You simulated it for 200 timesteps. Simulating it for longer (such as 5000 timesteps) shows a (qualitatively) sinusoidal solution.

Comment: 200 steps of size dt=0.01 makes for an endpoint of 0.01*200=2, as is visible in the graphs. The algorithm is correctly implemented. Just for the graph you should still get correct results with dt=0.1 // Note that for this pendulum model, the angle zero is the direction pointing down, pi is the direction of the unstable upright pendulum.

Comment: What they ^ said. Simulate for more time steps. As far as printing a list-like output, your data is in the lists `T`, `X`, and `Y`. Try `print(T)` and `print(X)` to see what they look like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As have been pointed out in the comments, the problem is that you chose only 20 samples for plotting. You can parameterize the number of samples as a function of the time, and thus get a graph where *t* ranges from 0 to 50, as you intended:

```
# Solving a non-linear pendulum equation of motion using RK4 method:
# Equation of Motion: d^x/dt^2 + k.sin(x)=0, where 'x' is angle, k=g/l. We take g=10m/s^2, l=10m, so k=1(s^{-2}).
# We modify the single 2nd order differential equation as a system of linear equations, consisting of two 1st order differential equation: (1) dx/dt=y=f1(x,y,t), (2) dy/dt=-k.sin(x)=f2(x,y,t).

from math import sin, pi

# Defining two functions-
def f1(t,x,y): return y

def f2(t,x,y): return -k*sin(x)

k=1.0                      #parameter
t,x,y=0,8.0*pi/9.0,0             #initial values (t: second, x: radian, y: (initial angular velocity) radian/second)
h=0.01                   #increment in t
T,X,Y=[t],[x],[y]          #lists to store data
tmax=50                  #max value of t (duration of the plot in units of time)
n=int(tmax/h)            #number of samples

# Loop starts with RK4 steps:
for i in range(n):
    a1=h*f1(t,x,y)                      
    b1=h*f2(t,x,y)                      
    a2=h*f1(t+0.5*h,x+0.5*a1,y+0.5*b1)  
    b2=h*f2(t+0.5*h,x+0.5*a1,y+0.5*b1)  
    a3=h*f1(t+0.5*h,x+0.5*a2,y+0.5*b2)  
    b3=h*f2(t+0.5*h,x+0.5*a2,y+0.5*b2)  
    a4=h*f1(t+h,x+a3,y+b3)              
    b4=h*f2(t+h,x+a3,y+b3)              
    x=x+(1/6)*(a1+2*a2+2*a3+a4)         # apprx. value of x1 for t+h
    y=y+(1/6)*(b1+2*b2+2*b3+b4)         # apprx. value of y1 for t+h
    t=t+h                               # current value of independent variable t
    T.append(t)
    X.append(x)
    Y.append(y)

    
# for plotting
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(T,X,lw=3)
plt.xlim(0,tmax)    # xlim is just time range
plt.ylim(-pi,pi)  # ylim is the range of angle (in radians)
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: Plot of the result, showing a sinusoidal-like curve.]

> Also, what should I do if, rather than looking at the plot, I want to get a list-like output, like a table with two columns for time and angle?

You already have the values for *time* and *angle* in variables `T` and `X`, respectively. If you don't want to use *numpy*, you could combine those arrays in a matrix-like structure like so:

```py
TX = [[t,x] for t,x in zip(T,X)]
```

As to your following question:

> Also also, what should be done so that we shall get the angle for a particular time (that is, for any external input)?

For an input that happens to be in your array *T*, you only have to get the corresponding element in array *X*. For an arbitrary value of time, you could do a linear interpolation between the closest samples. This could be more conveniently done using a function:

```py
def get_angle(t, T, X, h):
    # t: Any particular time (must be in the range used for T)
    # T: The time array you calculated earlier
    # X: The angle array you calculated earlier
    # h: Your time step (increment in t)

    i = t/h   # The corresponding sample index (not necessarily an integer)
    i0 = floor(i)
    i1 = ceil(i)
    x = (X[i1]-X[i0])*(i-i0)/(i1-i0) + X[i0]    # Linear interpolation between the two closest samples
    return x
```

Comment: For transforming the generator into a list you could also just use `list(zip(T,X))`. Or in the middle `[rec for rec in zip(T,X)]`. Or with numpy `np.array([T,X]).T`.